# PyWinAuto select File -> Open from Tableau Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a few steps in a process we have. There are 2 steps that I need to interact with tableau, I just want to press these buttons.

I follow the Notepad example that the pywinauto docs provide, but when I try to select a sub menu option, it keep failing.

`dlg.menu_select('File')` works

`dlg.menu_select('File -> Open')` doesn't work

`dlg.menu_select('File -> Open...')` doesn't work

TimeoutError: timed out

```
# Using .Server because .File gives me pdf info. Still a menu item.
dlg.Server.print_control_identifiers()
```

Control Identifiers:

Static - 'To a Server'    (L165, T685, R403, B711)
['To a ServerStatic', 'Static', 'To a Server']
child_window(title="To a Server", control_type="Text")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the file menu items either so I ended up using control characters.

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
from pywinauto.controls.menuwrapper import Menu, MenuItemInfo
from pywinauto import mouse

import win32api

send_keys('^o') # open file

send_keys('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Pareto.twbx', with_spaces = True)  # absolute file name

send_keys('{VK_RETURN}')  # accept file

updatedata = dlg.TableauPareto.child_window(title="Data Alt+D", control_type="MenuItem").wrapper_object()
updatedata.click_input() # open menu

x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()  # find cursor position
mouse.click(button='left', coords=(x+ 30, y+85)) # click on refresh data

send_keys('{VK_RETURN}') # refresh data

time.sleep(10) # wait for refresh

send_keys('{VK_RETURN}') # end
send_keys('^s')  # save file

app.kill(soft=False) # quit
```